# How can I play these notes on A and G strings?

Tags: guitar, chords, electric-guitar, tablature

I came up to these tabs showing a power-chord like chord on A and G strings.
How exactly can I play these without interfering with the D string?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an electric guitar with typical string spacing, it would actually be more difficult to play that *without* muting the D-string than with muting. Chances are, if you finger the octave just like you would the fifth in a two-string powerchord but one string higher, the index finger will already be resting lightly on the D-string and thus prevent it from sounding as an open D. Hover specifically for the 7th and 5th fret, the D string likely *would* sound as a natural harmonic (flageolett) A, which is also no good here. To prevent that, one option is to finger the entire thing as a *three-string* powerchord (E B E) with index, ring and pinky, but not actually press down the ring finger on the D-string. This way you should get reliable muting.

An alternative that I'd tend to pick for this passage is to keep the index finger as a semi-barree on the fifth fret the whole time (damping the D and higher strings) and fingering the E-octave with middle and pinky, then the D-octave with index and ring finger. This way you not only get good muting but also avoid needing to slide the entire hand between the two chords.

Answer (score 6):

Those are octaves, it's a common technique. Either you mute the in-between string with one of your left-hand fingers so that the D string doesn't sound, or you don't use a pick and finger only the sounding strings with your right hand. One way to do the muting is to tilt the A string finger so that it touches the D string and doesn't let it vibrate.

Answer (score 4):

The objective is to play the notes on the A and G strings, which means there's a string in between, in the way.

One way is to *mute* the string in between with a finger that's not being used. It simply touches that string, without pressing it down, so it makes a dull click, and that's it.

Or, as I prefer, play the strings using either a pick and an spare finger or just two fingers. That way, it's pretty straightforward to pick out the strings needed, and ignore any intervening strings.

Worth a little look at Mr. Thumb - who played octaves better than most of us play single notes! Reference Wes Montgomery.